SDWebImage is not resizing to full screen space
I am working on a SwiftUI view that displays images using WebImage from the SDWebImageSwiftUI library. I want the images to consistently fill the entire screen, regardless of their original size. However, some images are not resizing properly to cover the entire screen, while others do.
import SwiftUI
import SDWebImageSwiftUI

struct PhotoView: View {

var wallpaper: Wallpaper

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        
        
        WebImage(url: wallpaper.imageURL) { image in
            image.resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.fill/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
            
            
        } placeholder: {
            WebImage(url: wallpaper.thumbnailURL) { image in
                image.resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.fill/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                   
                
            } placeholder: {
                Rectangle().foregroundColor(.bgdLight)
                
            }
            
        }
        // Supports options and context, like `.delayPlaceholder` to show placeholder only when error
        .onSuccess { image, data, cacheType in
            // Success
            // Note: Data exist only when queried from disk cache or network. Use `.queryMemoryData` if you really need data
        }
        .transition(.fade(duration: 0.5))
        .scaledToFill()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.fill/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .clipped()
        
        
        
    }
    .background(.red)
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
}
}


Your codes look fine, I just copied your codes and I tested all kind of image types, it passed all cases. Can you give me us some example of that don't work ?
